# How do I put parentheses in lists?

Tags: list

So for this assignment we need to have random dice rolls added to a list, then we need to add parentheses around the repeating numbers. (example: (1,1,1),2,3,(4,4) )

```
from random import randint

diceTosses = []

for i in range(0, 20) :
    diceTosses.append(randint(1,6))

value = diceTosses

inRun = False

for i in range(1, len(diceTosses)):
    if inRun and diceTosses[i] != value[i - 1]:
        print(")", end="")
        inRun = False

inRun = True

for i in range(1, len(diceTosses)):
    if inRun and diceTosses[i] != [i + 1]:
        print("(", end="")
        inRun = True

print(diceTosses)
```

I successfully put rolls in a list, but My code seems to only print the leftmost parenthesis and its not in list, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Is this what your expected result?  (1 ,1 ,1 ,1),(2 ,2 ,2),(3 ,3 ,3 ,3 ,3 ,3),(5 ,5 ,5),(6 ,6 ,6 ,6)

Comment: to group the reapeating numbers but not change the order so like (1 ,1 ), 2 ,(3 ,3),1,(4 ,4), 2 ,6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code if you want to see the result like: 
(1 ,1 ,1 ,1),(2 ,2 ,2),(3 ,3 ,3 ,3 ,3 ,3),(5 ,5 ,5),(6 ,6 ,6 ,6)

```
diceTosses.sort()
inRun = True

for i in range(1, len(diceTosses)):
    if inRun:
        print("(", end="")
    if diceTosses[i] == diceTosses[i - 1]:
        print(diceTosses[i-1],",", end="")
        inRun = False
    else:
        print(diceTosses[i-1], end= "),")
        inRun=True
if inRun:
    print("(", end="")
print(diceTosses[i], end= ")")
```